# Advanced data consolidation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table, conditional-formatting, countif

I need to Combine/Consolidate Data dynamically between over 20 separate Excel workbooks.  The Column names and their relative position at the top row are the same. The positioning of each word under Column A in different positions and some lists are longer than others.

```
Column A1= Word     Column B1= Frequency    
       other               349  
       sorry               346  
       down                338
```

[Each data set represents a week of words counted and sorted by frequency]

I would like to combine and consolidate this data set of 20 workbooks into one list that can be added to and updated. Ideally Based off Column A and nested into the formula a COUNT IF condition. Column B minimum frequency of at least 15 across every week (every workbook).

In addition, Is it even possible to nest a REMOVE IF function, (a 2-way look up?) to the master list if any matching word from any week did not MATCH the COUNT IF condition? A minimum frequency of at least 15 across every week.

Any ideas?
Would it be easier if I tried to link the data set within one workbook and each week within a sheet? Each sheet would represent a week.

I know that I may be able to accomplish this task via Pivot Table but is that the only or best way to approach the issue and how would I go about creating a pivot table if so?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  It can combine data from multiple files into a single table, e.g.

http://dutchdatadude.com/combining-excel-files-using-power-query-for-excel/

I cant follow your "minimum frequency" requirements, but Power Query has lots of other transformation capabilities.  Perhaps if you can explain them in more detail and with examples I can point you in the right direction.